# My JavaScript code does not show the expected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to print objects from an API using JSON and AJAX and it works when I use `console.log` to view it. But my `generateCreatureDiv` function does not work for some reasons.

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var response = this.responseText;
      var creatureData = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(creatureData);

      // get a creature from the data

      for (var i = 0; i < creatureData.creatures.length; i++) {
        var creature = creatureData.creatures;
        console.log(creature[i]);
        document.getElementById("CreatureEntry").innerHTML = generateCreatureDiv(creature[i]);
      }

      function generateCreatureDiv(creature) {
        var CreatureDiv = $("<div />");
        console.log("hoe");
        CreatureDiv.id = "CreatureInfo";
        console.log("hoe")
        $("CreatureDiv").append("<h1>" + creature.name + "</h1>");
        console.log("hoe");
        $("CreatureDiv").append("<img>" + creature.image + "</img>");
        return CreatureDiv;
        console.log("hoe");

      }

      // create a select option  for the object
      // Have a


    }

  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/17f3jl", true);
  xhttp.send();



});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <script src="./stylesheet.css"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="CreatureEntry">
      <select id="SelectOption">
        
      </select>
    </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? That's a very poor description of a problem. What do you expect? What is actually happening? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `"` quotes in `$("CreatureDiv")`  .Its not select with any ID or Class.And on your code  Already declare with `var CreatureDiv = $("<div />");` .So change as like this

```
function generateCreatureDiv(creature) {
        var CreatureDiv = $("<div />");
        console.log("hoe");
        CreatureDiv.id = "CreatureInfo";
        console.log("hoe")
        $(CreatureDiv).append("<h1>" + creature.name + "</h1>");
        console.log("hoe");
        $(CreatureDiv).append("<img>" + creature.image + "</img>");
        return CreatureDiv;
        console.log("hoe");

      }
```

And change like this

```
document.getElementById("CreatureEntry").innerHTML += generateCreatureDiv(creature[i]);
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("CreatureEntry").innerHTML = generateCreatureDiv(creature[i]);
```

Because `innerHTML =generateCreatureDiv(creature[i]);` it will reset previous value on each time call

Answer (score 0):

This line is erasing all of the content of your DIV for each element of your array:

```
document.getElementById("CreatureEntry").innerHTML = generateCreatureDiv(creature[i]);
```

Remove the first part and just call your method and append the results?

```
$("CreatureEntry").append(generateCreatureDiv(creature[i]));
```

Also, you need to remove the quotes wherever you're referencing `$("CreatureDiv")` and use `$(CreatureDiv)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a beginner so some of these errors are new to me. I appreciate your help